# Python - start() and end() functions select tuple items

Tags: python, tuples

I made a very simple called `Hangman` and i have been trying to use `.start()` and `.end()` functions to get all the matches of user input.
These functions return a tuple. for example;

```
text = 'test'
hidden_word = list('_'*len(text))
for m in re.finditer('t', text):
     print('t found', m.start(), m.end())
```

Output > 
**('t found', 0, 1)**

**('t found', 3, 4)**
My question is > *how do I select items from the returned tuple?*

.start()[1] Gives **TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'**

Comment: `start()` returns an integer that is the position in the text where the match starts, while `end()` returns the ending position. There's *no* tuple involved in the code you show.

Comment: yes, without the parantheses its not a tuple, i didnt see that but. It returns the same way: `0 1` and `3 4`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't returning a tuple; you are creating a tuple each time you print.

If you want the value of `start`, just use `m.start()`; similarly for `end`.

Comment: yes Im aware of that, But how do I pick the second element of that tuple ? Since it is returned from the function `.start()` & `.end()` and `.start()[1]` doesn't allow me to pick the item.

Comment: @user6256879 well just don't create the tuple? if `.start()` gives you what you want why put it in a tuple and then try to extract it from the tuple?

Comment: oh, just realized how old this is and that OPs account is deleted, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I might as well answer this for sake of completeness. You are trying to index a integer which will result in a TypeError. You need to select from the Tuple:

```
import re

text = 'test'
hidden_word = list('_'*len(text))
for m in re.finditer('t', text):
     t = ('t found', m.start(), m.end())
     print(t)
     print(t[1])
```

Output:

```
('t found', 0, 1)
0
('t found', 3, 4)
3
```